# How do I mock a DynamoDB mapper load function using Mockito?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to write two unit tests that tests the load operation. One when the record is in the table and one when the record is not in the table. The one where the record is not in the table is easy. I can generate random keys and verify that nothing has been returned. Although I am having a lot of trouble mocking when record is in the table. Here is the logic I used.

```
arbitraryObject mockObject = generateArbitraryObject();
when(mockedMapper.load(itemKey)).thenReturn(mockObject)
```

However, when I try and print out the result in the load function after the `Mapper.load(itemkey)` is always gives me `null`, not `mockObject`. Therefore making my test fail. Does anyone know how I should go about testing it? Thanks

Comment: There's no reason that you can't mock out com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.IDynamoDBMapper.load(T keyObject) and have it return an object, so it sounds like you're probably doing something wrong. Unfortunately, you haven't posted the details that would show what that something is. Have you tried [creating a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I should add, by the way, that although you can mock out the mapper, it's better in many cases to use the embedded flavor of DynamoDBLocal. That way your unit-tests don't need to care *exactly* which mapper method is being called; you can just verify the observable behaviors. But mocking out the mapper is still useful for test-cases where the mapper needs to throw an exception.

Comment: @ruakh hmmm, I don't know what I did wrong. Just for the sakes of it I used the exact same logic to mock a hash map and it returned what I anticipated. I wonder where can I go wrong here.

Comment: I don't know what you did wrong, either; but the process of creating a minimal reproducible example might help you figure it out, and even if it doesn't, the minimal reproducible example itself will allow other people to help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would see if you can set the mapper in your constructor and in your unit test, you pass in the mockedMapper into the constructor.